# What's wrong with my fluid simulation...?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've been following this Blender Guru tutorial - https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-fluid-simulator - however, mine doesn't appear to be working properly. I'm not sure if there are Domain settings I need to adjust first, though I suspect it's more to do with the fluid itself. So far I've tried increasing the resolution, scaling the fluid object to make it smaller, decreasing the size of the Domain cube...

This is what happens when I bake it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OMio.jpg

[image]

Comment: Did it work before you bake it, or not at all? What happens if you play the animation?

Comment: Not at all. To be honest, I'm not even sure how you preview the simulation before baking. Nothing happens in Render mode anyway.

Comment: Bumpety bump. Anyone?

Comment: Okay, looks like I've had to look into this further without any help. After a bit of experimenting, it looks like there's something amiss with the starter file I downloaded, which keeps causing the Domain cube to mess up. Even before baking the simulation. I've tried appending just the mug with a fresh new scene, placed it within a cube, applied the appropriate physics, and it seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: Nope. Looks like I haven't fixed it after all. Once I've set everything up again, the same problem persists. :(

Comment: Be patient, not everyone is on the site 24/7. I played with the fluid simulation this weekend, had a similar issue. My inflow object was a sphere, as soon as I changed to a cube the issue was gone. Have you applied scale to the objects? Increase resolution? there are many things that can go wrong. I suggest deleting the domain / fluid and doing it again, there might be something you overlooked there.